# What is minting ERC20 in Uniswap v3 contract?

Tags: erc-20, erc-721, uniswap, defi, mint

I have been deep-diving Uniswap V3 and I came across this code example:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20Detailed.sol";

contract GLDToken is ERC20, ERC20Detailed {
    constructor(uint256 initialSupply) ERC20Detailed("Gold", "GLD", 18) public {
        _mint(msg.sender, initialSupply);
    }
}
```

What does this mean? I do not know since when _mint is added to `erc20.sol`.

Comment: Can you clarify what's the connection with Uniswap?

Answer (score 2):

It is using [this](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol) contract from open zeppelin which has a `_mint` function.

Above piece of code just mints the initial amount to the person who deploys the contract.